# Documents stuck in printer queue

Tags: printing

I am useless with computers I know but some documents are - I think - stuck in the queue and thus nothing will print. I have seen other answers which suggest that I should enter lpstat -o in a command line.  But what does that mean?  Where is a command line?

Comment: If you add the results of `lpstat -o` to your question I will make all the commands specific to this question. If unlear PM me and I'll add in more details.

Comment: For command line (terminal) - ctrl+Alt+T or search in dash for "terminal"

Answer (score 3):

Command line is a window where you can type commands. Open "dash" and search for "terminal". It will get you a command prompt. If you then type

```
lpstat -o
```

you will get a list all outstanding printjobs with their printer ID and job identification number. If you make a screenshot of that and include the URL to you question I will expand my anwser. Commands to help you get on ...

```
cancel {printjobID}
```

will delete that print job from the queue.

```
cancel -a {printerID}
```

will cancel ALL printjobs from the queue for that printer. You can also disable/enable the printer to see of the problem is network related

```
cupsdisable {printer ID}
cupsenable {printer ID}
```

(if network related you will see the queue clear itself and the printer printing again).